# What are the pros/cons of having many functions in few apps relative to having many function apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have 20 azure functions. About a half of them are service bus triggered, another half are timer triggered (mostly once per day). I'm wondering how to organize them properly. I'm going to use consumption plan. Docs say that they are scaled automatically and billed only for used resources. Does it mean that I can have a single host for all of them? Or maybe it's better to put timer triggered functions into one host (because they do not require scaling) and put all service bus function into another host? If I put all SB functions into one host, will it help for reducing cold starts?

Each host requires separate configuration, separate deployment and has its own set of ip addresses (I need to put them to Mongo firewall). That's why I would like to have as few hosts as possible but still do not want to hurt performance. I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale but still not sure. Does anybody have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"Properly" is a case by case, maybe even opinion based item.

All the pros of having more function apps with few functions within it are all offshoots of one thing.

**Isolation**

If ever a function runs out of memory then it can kill the underlying host so unrelated functions might kill others which can be tricky to debug

If you update a function it restarts the whole host so it might interrupt functions that you're not thinking about

Functions don't have internal venvs so if one function wants one version of a library and another function wants another then they have to be in separate functions

The cons are mostly **convenience** but here are ways to mitigate those cons

Cold starts: You can mitigate cold starts by adding a timer trigger function that runs just long enough to restart the hidden timer that shuts down the host.

Code sprawl, avoiding copy-paste: If you have common code that should be used amongst many functions then it seems you need to copy/paste it to all the different function apps. However, you can publish that common code to pypi and put it in the requirements.txt of all of them so they share the common code without copy-paste

Convenience isn't nothing so I certainly wouldn't recommend having every little script in its own function app but you just have to figure out that balance based on your own needs and knowledge of your own code.